# Gradle error when deploying to Nexus Repository

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, nexus3, maven-publish

Today, I have been migrating some Java plugins using maven to gradle. The plugins do successfully build properly however, I am having trouble automatically deploying them to our nexus. What I am trying to is upload my Java jar file automatically to nexus through grade's publish function.
[![Gradle Publish][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYj3k.png

The following is the error I am getting when attempting this through IntelliJ

```
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'maven'
   > Could not write to resource 'http://nexus.grandtheftmc.net/content/repositories/releases/net/grandtheftmc/wastedguns/1.2.8/wastedguns-1.2.8.jar'.
      > Connection reset

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

The following is a relavent snippet of the error with gradle's debug mode on:

```
    2021-07-13T18:06:40.978-0400 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection released: [id: 13][route: {}->http://nexus.grandtheftmc.net:80][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2021-07-13T18:06:40.978-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Upload http://nexus.grandtheftmc.net/content/repositories/releases/net/grandtheftmc/wastedguns/1.2.8/wastedguns-1.2.8.jar' completed
2021-07-13T18:06:40.978-0400 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.NetworkOperationBackOffAndRetry] Error in 'PUT http://nexus.grandtheftmc.net/content/repositories/releases/net/grandtheftmc/wastedguns/1.2.8/wastedguns-1.2.8.jar'. Waiting 2000ms before next retry, 1 retries left
2021-07-13T18:06:40.979-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.NetworkOperationBackOffAndRetry] Network operation failed
org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not write to resource 'http://nexus.grandtheftmc.net/content/repositories/releases/net/grandtheftmc/wastedguns/1.2.8/wastedguns-1.2.8.jar'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.putFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.put(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$3.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$3.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.put(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher$ModuleArtifactPublisher$1.run(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:272)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.NetworkOperationBackOffAndRetry.withBackoffAndRetry(NetworkOperationBackOffAndRetry.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher$ModuleArtifactPublisher.putResource(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:269)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher$ModuleArtifactPublisher.publish(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:230)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher$ModuleArtifactPublisher.publish(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:223)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.AbstractMavenPublisher.publish(AbstractMavenPublisher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.MavenRemotePublisher.publish(MavenRemotePublisher.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publisher.ValidatingMavenPublisher.publish(ValidatingMavenPublisher.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository$1.publish(PublishToMavenRepository.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.internal.PublishOperation.run(PublishOperation.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository.doPublish(PublishToMavenRepository.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.publish.maven.tasks.PublishToMavenRepository.publish(PublishToMavenRepository.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:506)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:491)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:474)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:271)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution$2.withWorkspace(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:174)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:408)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:395)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:388)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:374)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:170)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:150)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceUploader.upload(HttpResourceUploader.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.upload(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceUploader.upload(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceUploader.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.put(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:182)
    ... 153 more
2021-07-13T18:06:42.986-0400 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] 
2021-07-13T18:06:42.986-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Upload http://nexus.grandtheftmc.net/content/repositories/releases/net/grandtheftmc/wastedguns/1.2.8/wastedguns-1.2.8.jar' started
2021-07-13T18:06:43.102-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Upload http://nexus.grandtheftmc.net/content/repositories/releases/net/grandtheftmc/wastedguns/1.2.8/wastedguns-1.2.8.jar'
2021-07-13T18:06:43.102-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Execute publish for :publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository'
2021-07-13T18:06:43.102-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Executing task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository''
2021-07-13T18:06:43.102-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Snapshot outputs after executing task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository'' started
2021-07-13T18:06:43.102-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Completing Build operation 'Snapshot outputs after executing task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository''
2021-07-13T18:06:41.774-0400 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] 
2021-07-13T18:06:41.774-0400 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.internal.buildevents.TaskExecutionLogger] > Task :publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository FAILED
2021-07-13T18:06:42.986-0400 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Performing HTTP PUT: http://nexus.grandtheftmc.net/content/repositories/releases/net/grandtheftmc/wastedguns/1.2.8/wastedguns-1.2.8.jar
2021-07-13T18:06:42.987-0400 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: default
2021-07-13T18:06:42.987-0400 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
2021-07-13T18:06:42.987-0400 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {}->http://nexus.grandtheftmc.net:80][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2021-07-13T18:06:42.987-0400 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection leased: [id: 14][route: {}->http://nexus.grandtheftmc.net:80][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2021-07-13T18:06:42.987-0400 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {}->http://nexus.grandtheftmc.net:80
2021-07-13T18:06:42.987-0400 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to nexus.grandtheftmc.net/104.26.10.9:80
2021-07-13T18:06:43.017-0400 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] Connection established 172.27.235.237:60680<->104.26.10.9:80
2021-07-13T18:06:43.017-0400 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] http-outgoing-14: set socket timeout to 30000
2021-07-13T18:06:43.017-0400 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Executing request PUT /content/repositories/releases/net/grandtheftmc/wastedguns/1.2.8/wastedguns-1.2.8.jar HTTP/1.1
```

Based of this error, it looks like for some reason, the connection is reset midway through the upload. The jar file its self **is successfully built**. In fact, if I manually upload the artifact to nexus, it works just fine. So this leads me to believe the issue lies somewhere in the upload process in gradle?

The repository is a password-protected repository however, I do not believe this is a password issue **because a separate module of this project with a nearly identical configuration did successfully upload to nexus** (the non-identical part being the dependencies). This issue is also unlikely to be permission issues because I have full admin privileges on the repository I am trying to upload to.

For your reference, here is my build.grade:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "6.1.0"
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group 'net.grandtheftmc'
version '2.6.1'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.destroystokyo.com/repository/maven-public/'
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.grandtheftmc.net/content/repositories/releases/'
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
        credentials {
            username mavenUser
            password mavenPassword
        }
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://jitpack.io'
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://maven.sk89q.com/repo/'
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.viaversion.com'
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.citizensnpcs.co/'
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.sk89q.worldedit:worldedit-bukkit:6.1.4-SNAPSHOT'
    compileOnly 'net.citizensnpcs:citizensapi:2.0.22'
    compileOnly 'us.myles:viaversion:3.1.0'
    compileOnly 'com.destroystokyo.paper:paper-api:1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compileOnly 'org.spigotmc:spigot:1.12.2-R0.1'
    compileOnly 'net.buycraft:BuycraftX:10.3.0'
    compileOnly 'com.comphenix.protocol:ProtocolLib:4.6.0'
    compileOnly 'com.github.j0ach1mmall3:JLib:1.10.0'
    compileOnly 'net.grandtheftmc:wastedguns:1.2.6'
    compileOnly 'net.grandtheftmc:wastedvehicles:1.1.0'
    compileOnly 'net.grandtheftmc:wastedcops:1.1.0'
    compileOnly 'net.grandtheftmc:core:2.6.1'
    compileOnly 'net.grandtheftmc:houses:1.1.2'
    compileOnly 'com.gmail.filoghost.holographicdisplays:HolographicDisplays:1.0.0'
    implementation 'net.grandtheftmc:common:1.1.6'
    compileOnly 'com.earth2me:Essentials:2.0.0'
}

shadowJar {
    archiveFileName = project.name + ".jar"
    exclude 'META-INF', 'META-INF/**'
    destinationDirectory = file("build")
}

// Force character encoding in case the workspace was not set up correctly
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = 'gtm'
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://nexus.grandtheftmc.net/content/repositories/releases/'
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
            credentials {
                username mavenUser
                password mavenPassword
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am completely stumped as to what the issue can possibly be. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I still don't understand why this build.grade actually managed to work for 2 of my project modules, I did figure out what is wrong.

It appears that Nexus was rejecting builds uploaded over HTTP. And in fact, in order to successfully upload the builds to nexus you had to use HTTPS. Thus, simply modifying the publishing block to the following did the trick for me:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId = 'gtm'
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://nexus.grandtheftmc.net/content/repositories/releases/'
            credentials {
                username mavenUser
                password mavenPassword
            }
        }
    }
}
```